# Java RegEx Performance with Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE

Tags: java, regex, performance

I got a pretty simple regular expression I am using

```
%%(products?)%%
```

Now I want it to be able to match both products? and Products?. The obvious answer is to use the CASE_INSENSITIVE tag when compiling a pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("%%(products?)%%", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

But on the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) it says "Specifying this flag may impose a slight performance penalty." I therefore thought of an alternative, without the flag:

```
Pattern.compile("%%([Pp]roducts?)%%")
```

My question is: Which one would have better performance?

Comment: It's worth noting that the two versions are not equivalent: the version with the flag is completely case-insensitive, and will accept e.g. `%%pRODuct%%`, whereas the version without the flag is only case-insensitive in the letter `P`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a significant difference between the methods.

While `Pattern.compile("%%(products?)%%", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)` might seem less efficient than `Pattern.compile("%%([Pp]roducts?)%%")` at first glance, it's internal functioning is not exactly that of comparing each character with both their lower' and uppercase counterparts; What actually happens is that the first method does a range-check with Unicode's lower' and uppercase blocks, while the second makes literal comparison.

I don't have knowledge much deeper than that, but the important part is this simple, but very interesting test (results on my machine included at the end):

```
String base = "I have a product that is the product of my hard work." 
  + "Products are always nice, because I can win cash if I sell my products.\n" 
  + "The product of me making my product is cash, because cash is the product of selling my product.\n" 
  + "With the cash I win with my product, I can buy other people's products.";

int processRepeats = 1000000; //One million runs, enough to take time for each clocking.
int averageRepeats = 10;

long averager = 0;
int count = 0;

//Switch the commenting to test the opposing method.
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("products?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
//Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[Pp]roducts?");
Matcher m;
long clocking;
for (int i = 0; i < averageRepeats; i++) {
  clocking = System.nanoTime();
  for (int ii = 0; ii < processRepeats; ii++) {
    m = p.matcher(base); //Here because the "base" would change in a real environment.
    while (m.find()) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  clocking = System.nanoTime() - clocking;
  averager += clocking;
  //System.out.printf("This method found %9d matches in %15d nanos [%9.3f ms]\n", count, clocking, clocking / 1000000f);
}
System.out.printf("This method averages %15d nanos [%16.3f ms] for %d times executing %d runs.\n",
averager / averageRepeats, (averager / (float) averageRepeats) / 1000000f, averageRepeats, processRepeats);

//RESULTS ON MY MACHINE:

//FIRST METHOD: [3 runs to demonstrate/guarantee consistency]
//This method averages      5024404693 nanos [        5024,404 ms] for 10 times executing 1000000 runs.
//This method averages      5021385539 nanos [        5021,386 ms] for 10 times executing 1000000 runs.
//This method averages      5017170143 nanos [        5017,170 ms] for 10 times executing 1000000 runs.

//SECOND METHOD: [same deal]
//This method averages      5806310774 nanos [        5806,311 ms] for 10 times executing 1000000 runs.
//This method averages      5809879747 nanos [        5809,880 ms] for 10 times executing 1000000 runs.
//This method averages      5804277386 nanos [        5804,277 ms] for 10 times executing 1000000 runs.
```

---

As you can see, not only the first method is faster (at last depending on the machine it's running), but also the performance difference of almost 800 ms (8/10 s), considering a large amount of runs, might not be as negligible an impact as one might think!

Comment: Hmm. I get the opposite result when I run this example: An average of around 1800ms för the first one, and 1575ms for the second one.

Comment: Response for this was already posted in @Keppil 's answer's comments, for anyone interested.

Comment: I've run your test with yours two patterns and with the Keppli's one and these are the results: 
1.7 HotSpot 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode): 2514,836 ms (products?, CASE_INSENSITIVE); 1562,485 ms ([Pp]roducts?);  2146,102 ms ([Pp][Rr][Oo][Dd][Uu][Cc][Tt][Ss]?)
1.6 HotSpot 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode): 2772,884 ms (products?, CASE_INSENSITIVE); 2653,504 ms ([Pp]roducts?);  2339,058 ms ([Pp][Rr][Oo][Dd][Uu][Cc][Tt][Ss]?). It seems than from JRE 1.6 to 1.7 there is more difference and CASE_INSENSITIVE really introduce a performance penalty

Answer (score 3):

Since the case insensitive version is the equivalent of

```
Pattern.compile("%%([Pp][Rr][Oo][Dd][Uu][Cc][Tt][Ss]?)%%")
```

it is pretty clear that you get some kind of performance penalty.

So in your case the last version would be slightly more effective (and also more limited).
*However*, in this case (and probably most cases) I'd say that the penalty is small enough to ignore. If your application is really performance intensive, you can always do a benchmark to see if the speedup is noticeable.

Comment: Is that actually what happens in the background for case insensitive expressions?

Comment: @climbage: I don't know the exact internal representation, but the important part is that in one way or another all those combinations must be checked.

Comment: Gotcha.  Either way you're still right, the performance hit will be negligible

Comment: I new the performance hit is negligible either way but just wanted to understand.

Comment: @hbtest - That's not quite what really happens, see my answer for some more details, as well as a very interesting (and maybe shocking) performance test.

Comment: @Keppil Sorry for taking away the best answer, but his answer is the opposite of yours and he has evidence to back it up.

Comment: @hbtest: No worries of course. However, I get the oposite result when I run TheLima:s benchmark, so it doesn't look like the best evidence.

Comment: Actually, @TheLima:s program seems to back up my statement, since I get almost exactly the same performance for my "equivalent" `Pattern` and the case insensitive one.

Comment: @Keppil There is some difference in resource consumption between the methods, so a machine which has a faster/slower IO-delays (seek-time, read/write), RAM memory and/or CPU will give such result-variation. ___ The point of my answer is that using the case-insensitive flag does not exactly make the method behave in a `literal comparison` way, and that depending from machine to machine, using either might be faster. =D